# Understanding Uhlmann Monotonicity Theorem on von Neumann Algebras

Tags: entropy, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-information

This is my first post, so apologies if this is a bad post.

I'm reading "Quantum Entropy and its use' by M.  Ohya and D. Petz. Theorem 5.3 states

> Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be von  Neumann algebras with positive normal functionals $\phi_1, \omega_1$ and $\phi_2, \omega_2$ respectively. Let $\alpha:M_1 \to M_2$ be a [unital] Schwarz map  [as in, $\alpha(x^*x) \ge \alpha(x)^* \alpha(x)$ for all $x\in M_1$] such that $\phi_2 \circ \alpha \le \phi_1$ and $\omega_2 \circ  \alpha \le \omega_1$. Then $S(\omega_1, \phi_1 )\le S(\omega_2, \phi_2)$ [$S$ is the relative entropy]

brackets mine.

This seems to yield the following contradiction:

Say $M_1 = M_2$ and $\alpha = id$ the identity map. Then $\alpha$ is a unital Schwarz map and the following holds for $0<\epsilon<1$:
$\phi \circ \alpha  \le \epsilon^{-1} \phi$ and $\omega \circ \alpha \le \epsilon^{-1} \omega,$ for any two positive normal functionals $\phi$ and $\omega$. Then the theorem as stated would imply  $S(\omega, \phi) \le \epsilon S(\omega, \phi)$, hence $S(\omega, \phi) \equiv 0$, which is a contradiction.

Is there an extra assumption that I'm missing in the statement of this theorem?  There is no errata for this book (that's publicly available, at least) so any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The post is not bad at all. This looks like a more abstract/terse version of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_subadditivity_of_quantum_entropy#Monotonicity_of_quantum_relative_entropy). Is this true ? Why does it hold that $\phi\circ\alpha\le \epsilon^{-1}\phi$ for all $0<\epsilon<1$ ? ( I am neither an expert of Uhlmann's work, nor did I know about this book. But I like such stuff a lot .)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) I think this is really similar to the monotonicity of relative entropy you mention. This theorem seems more general (to me at least) because one is allowed to choose $\phi_1,\omega_1$ (resp. the  2's) independently.  The inequality I mention for a contradiction just follows because I'm multiplying $\phi$ by a number greater than 1.

Comment: Right. To reach $\phi\le \epsilon^{-1}\phi$ was easy. Another stupid question: I did not know that the (mutual) entropy $S(\omega,\phi)$ (resp. $S(\omega)$) is linear in its arguments (or at least allows to pull out $\epsilon$). To reach a wider audience please formulate your ideas in terms of density matrices, projection operators, traces and so on. By peeking into Ohya  & Petz they recommend this even themselves. Unfortunately google shows only a limited part of that book.

Comment: I'm not familir enough with this stuff, but it looks to me that what you get is $S(\omega,\phi)\leq0$. Not sure if it is still a contradiction.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, you're right. Unfortunately I think it is still a contradiction because of the Quantum Pinsker inequality, which would imply $\omega = \phi$.

Comment: @KurtG. I absolutely will. I'm still working on it but I'll edit the post if I can write up a decent proof in the finite dimensional case.

Comment: @SalvorStranger, if you refer to theorem 5.1.i in the book you mention, you'll see that $S(\epsilon^{-1}\phi,\epsilon^{-1}\omega)=\epsilon^{-1}S(\phi,\omega)$, and this removes the contradiction. Using density matrices for which $S(\phi,\omega)=Tr(\phi\ln(\phi) - \phi\ln(\omega))$, may help in confirming the result.